# Access website using server name instead of www

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing, iis-6

I am new to IIS, setting up servers and load balancer so please do not mind my ignorance.

I have an old website, say, `www.mywebsite.com`.

There are 3 IIS 6.1 web servers on which my ASP.NET code is hosted.

Lets call them `web01`, `web02` and `web03`.

They are identical in configuration like OS, etc.

There is a load balancer which handles the requests coming in from the clients through `www` and routes it to the respective server based on whatever algorithm is put in place.

However, we were able to send requests directly to individual servers like this `web01.mywebsite.com` for all 3 servers.

I do not have access to the load balancer.

Recently there were some problems with the `web02` server so the client took it out from the load balancer.

We then reinstalled IIS and now, when we are trying to access the server using `web02.mywebsite.com`, it is throwing `404 - Not Found` error.

I am able to open the website from inside the server using `www.mywebsite.com` and I am able to see that the requests is catered by the `web02` server.

However, from inside the server also `web02.mywebsite.com` is throwing `404 - Not Found` error.

I am sure I am missing something in configuration at the IIS level but not able to figure out.

I tried searching on the internet but they all gave me generic solutions.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved on my own.

Strangely there was not a single answer or comment to this question.

I will try to answer so that others might also benefit.

There were 2 things that were required, out of which 1 was already present in my case:

1. In the `hosts` file, the mapping of IP address of the server to the actual name of the server should be present (This was there in my case)
2. In IIS, under bindings, I removed the host name i.e. www.mywebsite.com.

I was able to figure this through the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204032/setting-the-hostname-in-iis-bindings-breaks-website) and [here](https://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/) although they did not give the answer directly.

Hope this helps others.